# Issuer Alternative Name in python crypto

Tags: python, certificate, x509certificate, pyopenssl

Is there a way to make a alternative issuer name with a extension in a x509?
My Code so far:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

def generate_self_signed_cert(cert_dir, is_valid=True):
    """Generate a SSL certificate.

    If the cert_path and the key_path are present they will be overwritten.
    """

    #Keys
    private_key=crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,open("/root/Desktop/Key2","rb").read())
    public_key=crypto.load_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,open("/root/Desktop/Key1","rb").read())
    # create a self-signed cert
    cert = crypto.X509()
    cert.get_subject().C = 't'
    cert.get_subject().ST = 't'
    cert.get_subject().L = 's'
    cert.get_subject().O = 'd'
    cert.get_subject().OU = 'g'
    cert.get_subject().CN = 'g'
    cert.set_serial_number(01)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(3655555555)
    cert.set_issuer(cert.get_subject())
    cert.set_pubkey(public_key)
    cert.add_extensions([
        crypto.X509Extension("basicConstraints", False, "CA:FALSE"),
        crypto.X509Extension("keyUsage", True, "Digital Signature, Non Repudiation"),
    ])

    cert.set_version(2)
    cert.sign(private_key, 'sha256')


    with open(cert_dir+"Cert.cert", 'w+') as fd:
       fd.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))



generate_self_signed_cert("/root/Desktop/")
```

The code works fine. I just need to add a alternative issuer name. That should be done with the extensions, right?

Comment: Yes. I don't often see issuer alternative names, but subject alternative names are very common. Are you sure you don't want a subject alternative name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the answer to this question is:

```
 crypto.X509Extension("issuerAltName",False,"email:"+"test")
```